# jQuery - IE returning 0 children

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, children

I quickly made this function for a script im using:

```
$.fn.liCount = function(){
    var i=0;
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        i++;
    });
    return Number(i);
}
```

problem is IE returns 0, anyone know why?

```
alert( $("ul").liCount() );
```

edit:

```
<div id="prev-quotes">
    <ul id="quote-list">
        <li id="quote_content_wrapper" >
            <ul>
                <li class="quote_li">
                    <span class="service_quote"><a href="#">Web Design Services</a></span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="cost_quote"><strong>£192</strong> - <a id="7" href="#">delete</a> | <a id="7" href="#">view</a></span>
                </li>
                <li class="quote_li">
                    <span class="service_quote"><a href="#">Web Design Services</a></span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="cost_quote"><strong>£192</strong> - <a id="7" href="#">delete</a> | <a id="7" href="#">view</a></span>
                </li>
                <li class="quote_li">
                    <span class="service_quote"><a href="#">Web Design Services</a></span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="cost_quote"><strong>£192</strong> - <a id="7" href="#">delete</a> | <a id="7" href="#">view</a></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="first-quote" href="#">Previous Quotes</a>
            <img height="16" width="16" id="warning" src="images/for_web/check_mark.png">
        </li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```
$("ul > li").length;
```

See **[Child Selector (“parent > child”)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)**

If you want to get the number of `li` inside `ul` with id `quote-list`, you can use

```
$("#quote-list > li").length;
```

If you want to get the number of li with class names quote_li, you can use

```
$("#quote-list > li > ul > li.quote_li").length;
```

Comment: still not working:
element_delete.parents('li:eq(0)').remove();
      if( $("#quote-list > li > ul > li.quote_li").length == 5 ){
       $("#quote_content_wrapper").css("height", "auto");
      }else if( $("#quote-list > li > ul > li.quote_li").length == 0 ){
       $("#warning").attr("src", "images/for_web/warning.png");
      }

Answer (score 0):

There’s no need to use `return Number(i);` when you’re certain `i` is a number.

You don’t even need a counter var at all — there’s [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) in jQuery.

Why not just use the following instead:

```
$.fn.liCount = function() {
 return $(this).children('li').length;
};
```

It’s shorter, faster, more readable, and [it works in all browsers](http://jsbin.com/umesu).

However, it seems a little verbose / unnecessary to write a ‘plugin’ for this. You could just use something like:

```
$('ul > li').length;
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the HTML you’re using? Also, which IE version are you talking about? Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: latest version of IE and jQuery

Comment: http://www.web-design-contractor.co.uk/
user: codingforums
pass: password
just keep clicking next on the form untill you see the green tick appear instead of the red warning sign. Refresh page and do again and then click on "previous quotes" and delete 1. The warning sign should only re-appear when all have been deleted. IE changes after one delete.

Comment: Assuming your mean the warning sign in the Previous Quotes box, it appeared after I deleted 1 (ie. there was still 1 there). `$('ul > li').length;` should work correctly, so check that there's not something else breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

In IE 7 and 8 you need to identify the child tag

```
$.fn.liCount = function(){
    var i=0;
    $(this).children("li").each(function(){
        i++;
    });
    return Number(i);
}
```

will work. Of course this limits the use of the method unless you pass in the element you wish to count like...

```
    $.fn.liCount = function(elem){
        var i=0;
        $(this).children(elem).each(function(){
            i++;
        });
        return Number(i);
   }
```

then call

alert( $("ul").liCount("li") );